# Replacing string value in a pandas dataframe column inside a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe like this:

```
  ___________________________
 |  columnn                  |
 ____________________________
 | [happiness#sad]           |
 | [happy ness#moderate]     |
 | [happie ness#sad]         |
 ____________________________
```

and I want to replace the “happy ness”,”happiness”,”happie ness” with 'happyness' . I am currently using this method but nothing is changed.

```
  string exactly matching 
  happy ness===> happyness
  happiness  ===> happyness
  happie ness===>happyness
```

I treid the below two approaches

1st Approach

```
   df['column']
   df.column=df.column.replace({"happiness":"happyness" ,"happy ness":"happyness" ,"happie ness":"happynesss" })
```

2nd Approach

```
   df['column']=df['column'].str.replace("happiness","happyness").replace(“happy ness”.”happyness”).replace(“happie ness”,”happynesss”)
```

Desired Output:

```
           ______________________
          |  columnn             |
           _______________________
          | [happyness,sad]      |
          | [happyness,moderate] |
          | [happyness,sad]      |
          _______________________
```

Comment: your columns have list?

Comment: Yes I am having a list in a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `replace` with `regex=True`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"columnn": [["happiness#sad"], ["happy ness#moderate"], ["happie ness$sad"]]})
data = {"happiness":"happyness" ,"happy ness":"happyness" ,"happie ness":"happynesss" }
df["columnn"] = df["columnn"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).replace(data, regex=True).tolist())
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                columnn
0       [happyness#sad]
1  [happyness#moderate]
2      [happynesss$sad]
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh for helping out this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach i think this will work for you.

```
df['new_col']=df['column'].replace(to_replace = 
['happyness','happiness','happie ness'], value = 
['happyness','happyness','happyness'])
```

Comment: The  above approach is not working @venkatadileep
Thanks for your effort